# How to use confirmPasswordReset(code, newPassword) in firebase API?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am going to use 2 firebase APIs for forgot password function.

```
1 sendPasswordResetEmail
2 confirmPasswordReset
```

When I called sendPasswordResetEmail, Firebase Api sent password reset url to my email,but now I have to get verify code to be param of confirmPasswordReset.
I want to know where does "code" comes from in confirmPasswordReset function.
(I can't see code in my email, Firebase API only sent password reset url)

Comment: The code must be part of the URL you got in e-mail. It is passed as query parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The code is present in the clickable link that's in the email Firebase sends to the user. In [your template](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/emails), you can see it as:

```
https://yours.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=<action>&oobCode=<code>
```

The code needed is the value of the `oobCode` parameter.

Comment: Thank, and is there any other convenient method?
forexample, code: 2233 
So users can easily know and select it.