# How to know when a user has changed the password in firebaseAuthentication?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Currently I'm using two databases to administrate users, what I'm trying to do is to update the firebaseAuth password when the user isn't logged (by sending passwordResetEmail).

Then when the user changes the password (in firebase) and log in again, if the FirebaseLogin is successful I'll take the password and I'll reset the password in the other database.

So, what I need is to know when a user has changed the password in firebase

there's a method from firebaseAuth that sends to the user a password reset email, I need a way to know when the user have changed his password, I've found two methods from firebaseAuth:

```
confirmPasswordReset();
checkActionCode();
```

I think that using both methods it could be possible to identify a password reset action, but I don't know how to use these methods.

The other way it would be to save the password directly in Firebase database, to use addValueEventListener or something similar, but I would prefer to avoid saving passwords in the Firebase database.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42278014/how-to-use-confirmpasswordresetcode-newpassword-in-firebase-api

Comment: I've already seen it, thanks, It would be useful, but now the question would be: how can I get That value?, It's changing for each request.

Comment: are u gonna save the new password in the database after?

Comment: Yes I will, But It wouldn't be in firebaseDatabase, I could save it there (in firebaseDB) but It would be in plane text, and I'd preffer not to do it.

Comment: did the answer help you?

Comment: Yes, I'm actually using Android, but It helped me a lot, thaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would probably to create a custom reset-password email handler.  Instead of doing the work in your app to verify that a password was just reset, you can handle the reset yourself (and reset it in both places at once). You can read about implementing this [in the auth guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler).

The `confirmPasswordReset()` and `checkActionCode()` methods you mentioned are both supposed to be used from inside the custom email handler.

You definitely do not want to be saving your user's passwords in plain text anywhere. If you have to save them in a second location, always make sure they are encrypted with a unique salt.  If you want to verify your Firebase users' identity on a second system, other methods you could use are: [re-use their Firebase auth tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), use the [REST api to verify their password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-email-password), or export your users [using the cli](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth) and verify them yourself using [Firebase's Scrypt library](https://github.com/firebase/scrypt)

Comment: thanks for answering me, I'll try to use REST api, I found it interesting

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use this method:

```
confirmPasswordReset();
```

you need the actioncode and the newpassword entered by the user.

> Completes the password reset process, given a confirmation code and new password.

more info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#confirmPasswordReset

So first you need to get the actioncode:

```
var actionCode = getParameterByName('oobCode');
```

then you need to verify the action code and get a new password from the user and pass it to confirmPasswordReset:

```
auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(actionCode).then(function(email) {
var accountEmail = email;
 auth.confirmPassordReset(actionCode, newPassword).then(function(resp) {
 // Password reset has been confirmed and new password updated.

  }).catch(function(error) {
   //error
});
}).catch(function(error) {
   //error
});
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler